# How to print differences between 2 elements of an array in a form of another array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

As an example I have an array of 5 elements:

**Input array:**

***ele = [2, 5, 9, 1, 4]***

I want to output an array that has difference between all the elements but not repeated difference (ie, I don't want to count ele[1] - ele[5] and then again ele[5] - ele[1])

**My output array should be**

*diff_array = [ele[1]-ele[2], ele[1]-ele[3], ele[1]-ele[4], ele[1]-ele[5], ele[2]-ele[3], ele[2]-ele[4], ele[2]-ele[5], ele[3]-ele[4], ele[3]-ele[5], ele[4]-ele[5]]*

***diff_array = [-3, -7, 1, -2, -4, 4, 1, 8, 5, -3]***

I want to write this in python. I guess I will have to make nested for loop but I am not getting it right. It is a small part of my full code. Any help will be really appreciated. Have been trying all kind of stuff but doesn't give me right answer.

Thank you very much!

Comment: In python index starts from `0`.

Comment: sorry, but using itertools you will learn nothing. Better make a nested loop, so you can learn. the trick is that the outer variable `i` should go from 0 to len-1 (skipping the last element) and the inner loop variable `j` should not start at 0, but start at `i+1` and go until the end (including the last element). Once you understand how this nested loops work and why you start at `i+1` and not at 0 you can then delegate the combinations to itertools

Answer (score 1):

You can do with nested for loops:

```
ele = [2, 5, 9, 1, 4]
lst = []
for x in range(len(ele)):
    for y in range(x+1,len(ele)):
        lst.append(ele[x]-ele[y])
```

With List comprehension:

```
[ele[x]-ele[y] for x in range(len(ele)) for y in range(x+1,len(ele))]

#output
[-3, -7, 1, -2, -4, 4, 1, 8, 5, -3]
```

Or as @Jon Suggested with itertools:

```
import itertools    
print([x[0] - x[1] for x in itertools.combinations(ele, 2)])
```

Comment: For looping answer, would need to append to an originally empty List rather than print to get OP result,

Answer (score 0):

```
def diff(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    r = []
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            r.append(arr[i]-arr[j])
    return r
 arr = [2, 5, 9, 1, 4]

 new_arr = diff(arr)

 print(new_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
ele = [2, 5, 9, 1, 4]

# Initialize an empty list to store the differences
diff_array = []

# Iterate over all pairs of elements
for i in range(len(ele)):

    for j in range(i + 1, len(ele)):
        # Calculate the difference and append it to the list
        diff = ele[i] - ele[j]
        diff_array.append(diff)

# Print the result
print(diff_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

For each element, you need to compute differences with all the subsequent elements.  The `enumerate()` function can help with the nested loops by providing you with value and indexes at the same time.  Using a comprehension with the nested loop gives you the differences in a single statement:

```
ele = [2, 5, 9, 1, 4]

diff = [ a-b for i,a in enumerate(ele,1) for b in ele[i:] ]

print(diff)

[-3, -7, 1, -2, -4, 4, 1, 8, 5, -3]
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I want to output an array that has difference between all the elements but not repeated difference ..."*

Here is an example.

Traverse *a*, and sub-traverse the remaining items; appending the difference to *b*.

```py
n, b = len(a := [2, 5, 9, 1, 4]), []
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    for j in range(i + 1, n):
        b.append(x - a[j])
```

Output

```
[-3, -7, 1, -2, -4, 4, 1, 8, 5, -3]
```